# Error while installing Icehouse openstack using devstack

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, openstack, devstack

I am trying to install the icehouse openstack on Ubuntu 12.04 amd64, which is in VirtualBox. I am using devstack to do so. So, I am executing the script "stack.sh". While executing it throws this error:

> IOError:[Error 2]No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools.egg-info'

I even updated and upgraded the Ubuntu (by running the command `sudo apt-get update/upgrade`),before downloading the devstack and it took a long time, but even after that, the error still comes.

Comment: Check which branch of DevStack you are using. For Icehouse you must be in stable/icehouse branch

Comment: You mean, to run for this command? git clone https://github.com/.../devstack.git -b stable/icehouse, I was using this command only for cloning the devstack, but still getting the error

Comment: Again, the command i ran to clone the devstack was: git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git -b stable/icehouse

Comment: Ok, good, check if you have setuptools installed correctly, if you don't have it try to install it manually or try to re-install it if you already have it.

Comment: FWIW, I'm having the same issues w/ a vagrant box running ubuntu 12.04...no clue why this error happens but it has been doing since around Feb 4th.

Answer (score 1):

artemdevel is right!

Run the following and you should be good to go :

`sudo rm /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools.egg-info
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-setuptools`